# Prove that $\mathscr{G}$ is Countable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\mathscr{G} = \{N(p;r) \, : \, \, p, r \in \mathbb{Q} \, \, \, \mathrm{and} \, \, \,r > 0\}$.

(a) Prove that $\mathrm{G}$ is countable.

(b) Let $A$ be a nonempty open set and let $\mathrm{G}_A = \{N \in \mathrm{G} \, : \, N \subseteq A\}$. Prove that $\bigcup \{N \, : \, N \in \mathrm{G}_A \} = A$.

(a) I divided this part into two cases.

1. First, I assumed that $\mathscr{G}$ was finite. If $\mathscr{G} = \varnothing$, then we're done. Otherwise, suppose that $|\mathscr{G}| = k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we can enumerate the elements of $\mathscr{G}$ as $(p_1-r, p_1 + r) \dotsc (p_k-r, p_k+r)$, so $\mathscr{G}$ is countable when finite.
2. On the other hand, if $\mathscr{G}$ is infinite, then I think we can proceed similarly as in the first part: If we extend $k$ to infinity, we have the sequence of open intervals $(p_1-r,p_1+r), \dotsc, (p_n-r,p_n+r), \dotsc$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so, again, $\mathscr{G}$ is countable.

$\enspace$Therefore in both cases, $\mathscr{G}$ is countable.

(b) I did not get far in this part, but I do have an outline. I believe I would, again, consider cases where $\bigcup \{N \, : \, N \in \mathrm{G}_A \}$ is finite and denumerable, since I was not given a lower bound for the $\bigcup$. So I assumed that $\bigcup \{N \, : \, N \in \mathrm{G}_A \}$ is finite and proceeded as follows:

1. Let $I = \{1, \dotsc, k\}$ be an indexing set. Let $N \in \bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr{F}$ where $\mathscr{F} = \{N_i: N_i \in \mathscr{G}_A\}$. Then for some $i_0 \in I$, we have $N_{i_0} \in \mathscr{G}_A$. Hence $N_{i_0} \subseteq A$. Therefore, $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathscr{F} \subseteq A$.

$\enspace$ Now let $x \in A$. Since $A$ is open, $x$ is an interior point. But I do not know how to proceed here. 
$\enspace \enspace$ Whether or not $x$ is rational or irrational, I cannot find a particular neighborhood that is a subset
$\enspace$ of the finite union.

Because of this, I have not proceeded to the denumerable case.

Any insight concerning my approach, problems with it, etc. woudld be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $N(p;r)$ mean?

Comment: He's probably in a metric space and this is an open ball. For item (a) you can just say that $f: \{  N(p, r) \mid r \in \Bbb Q_{>0} \} \to \Bbb Q$ given by $f(N(p,r)) = r$ is an injection and $\Bbb Q$ is countable. Done, no need for complications..

Comment: don't you want in the definition $p\in\mathbb Q$  ?

Comment: I edited the post to include $p \in \mathbb{Q}$. Also $N(p,r) = (p-r,p+r)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll extend my comment to an answer. You do not need to break everything into complicated cases.

For item (a), define $f\colon \{N(p,r)\mid r \in \Bbb Q_{>0}\} \to \Bbb Q$ putting $f(N(p,r)) = r$. Then $f$ is injective and $|\{N(p, r)\mid r \in \Bbb Q_{>0}\}| \leq |\Bbb Q| = \aleph_0$.

For item (b) use the definition: since $N \subseteq A$ for all $n \in {\rm G}_A$, take unions to obtain $\bigcup \{N \mid N \in {\rm G}_A\}\subseteq A$. On the other hand, let $x \in A$. There is $r > 0$ such $x \in N(x,r) \subseteq A$. Then $x \in N(x,r)$ and $N(x,r) \in {\rm G}_A$. With this, $x \in N(x,r) \subseteq \bigcup\{N \mid N \in {\rm G}_A\}$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $A \subseteq \bigcup\{N \mid N \in {\rm G}_A\}$.

Comment: what does $p$ do in this question and answer ? If $p\in \mathbb R$ then the family in question is not  countable.

Comment: The point $p$ is fixed. *Given* p, the set $\{ N(p,r) \mid r \in \Bbb Q_{>0}\}$ is countable. In the second part of the answer I used $x$ instead of $p$ just because whatever (it is only notation)

Comment: I think I understood your doubt. We're thinking $N(p,r) = \{ q \mid d(p,q) < r \}$. More exactly, $N({\rm point}, {\rm radius})$ and not $N({\rm radius},{\rm point})$.

Comment: to me the problem is not clearly stated, I would tend to believe it could have been $\mathscr{G} = \{N(p;r) \, : \ p \in \mathbb{Q}, \ r \in \mathbb{Q} \, \, \, \mathrm{and} \, \, \,r > 0\}$. But what if it were $\mathscr{G} = \{N(p;r) \, : \ p \in \mathbb{R}, \ r \in \mathbb{Q} \, \, \, \mathrm{and} \, \, \,r > 0\}$. How do I know if the OP did not specify?

Comment: But this could be an arbitrary metric space $(X,d)$, not $\Bbb R$, so there's no reason to assume $p \in \Bbb Q$, a priori. I just treated the problem in the most general way I could. But yes, I agree with you, OP could've stated it more precisely.

Comment: If $p$ were fixed then part (b) would not work. If $p\in\mathbb R$ then part (a) would not work. The question was just edited, defining $\mathscr{G} = \{N(p;r) \, : \, \, p, r \in \mathbb{Q} \, \, \, \mathrm{and} \, \, \,r > 0\}$.